# Using Multiple ors on filter

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table which has a field holding pack sizes which can be in different formats.
For example
Pack of 1
1 Pack
(Pack of 1)
1 x ....
[image: Pack size table]

I have set up a table where I hold a number of combinations for these

For each line in the above I would like to fiter another table so I get as many combinations for the pack size in col a filtered in the data datable which I can then update with the packsize from cola a.
[image: tabe to filter and updates]

I thought that Filter with array criteria would let me set up the 7 filters based on cols b - H .... The first filter needs to be and Ends With otherwise if i filtered just Pack of 1 i also get Pack of 10, Pack of 100 etc...

I hope this makes sense as to what I am trying to do - I just need some guidance on how the Autofilter statement in VBA would work

[image: Values of filter strings]

ApdTbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=PackFilter1, Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:=PackFilter2

The above works for 2 criteria selections

if I try
ApdTbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=PackFilter1, Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:=PackFilter2, Operator:=xlOr, Criteria3:=PackFilter3

I get error saying Compile Error Named Argument already specified

ApdTbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Array(PackFilter1), Operator:=xlOr works and creates this filter
[image: Filter1]

ApdTbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Array(PackFilter1, PackFilter2), Operator:=xlOr only generates the second selection on the filter...
[image: filter2]

ApdTbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Array(PackFilter1, PackFilter2), Operator:=xlFilterValues works and creates filter
[image: filter 3]

ApdTbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Array(PackFilter1, PackFilter2, PackFilter3), Operator:=xlFilterValues results in this filter
[image]
and the rows with values from Packfilter2 Packfilter3 are shown but not Packfilter1

Comment: The linked threads explain that you can't filter more than two criteria with wildcards, and that an alternative is to build an array of matching values and filter on that.

Comment: thanks i did search but missed the wild card relevance.... What I may do is process the wildcard selection then the rest!

Comment: If filtering gets too complicated, an option could be to create a helper column (either using a formula or with VBA code) holding a True/False value filter for that.

Comment: @FunThomas thanks for that suggest that sounds easier!